# Table columns acting as rows when zooming page

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, web

I made a table with 2 rows and 5 columns in my web application. It works ok when i view it from a browser. 
[image]

There is a problem when i try to view the page from a mobile device, the zoom makes the cells useless. That is why i want the display to look like this:

[image]

To explain the picture, I want to display columns as rows when viewing the page from a device with a small screen. Is there a possibility to dinamically alter the table if the page is zoomed to some proportion, or do I have to make two different pages, one for normal browsing, and one for browsing with devices that have small screens?

Thank You.

Comment: you mean web responsiveness?

Comment: Yes, when You zoom in or out in the browser (Ctrl +, Ctrl -) the table displays differently.

Comment: you should use media queries target the width on mobile and make your elements width 100%